# Find closest point from target point in leaflet

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I have two points in leaflet map

```
First Point Coordinate: [31.470186399999996,74.3003215]
Second Point Coordinate: [31.471325,74.298713]
```

And one target point

```
target point Coordinate: [31.469706,74.299285]
```

Now i want to know which point is closest to target point with respect to route distance? How can i determine it?

**Note**: Map can also have multiple points.

Comment: the distance between two points is just the difference |a-b|

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find closest marker leaflet.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622814/how-to-find-closest-marker-leaflet-js)

Answer (score 0):

just a single operation

```
distance2(point1,point2) //the square distance 
{
    return (point1[0]-point2[0])*(point1[0]-point2[0])+
           (point1[1]-point2[1])*(point1[1]-point2[1])
}
const min=this.distance2(pointFirst,point)<this.distance(pointSecont,point)?pointFirst:pointSecond
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want true distance between two points rather than an approximation, you can use `turf.js` functions...

```
var point1 = turf.point([point1.lng, point1.lat]);
var point2 = turf.point([point2.lng, point2.lat]);
var options = {units: 'metres'};
var distance = turf.distance(point1, point2, options);
```

turf.js: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf